# Get JSON request from link into R

Tags: r, json

I am trying to learn how to collect data from the Web into R. There's a website from Brazilian Ministery of Health that is sharing the numbers of the disease here in Brazil, it is a public portal.

[COVIDBRASIL](https://covid.saude.gov.br/)

So, on this page, I am interested in the graph that displays the daily reporting of cases here in Brazil. Using the inspector on Google Chrome I can access the JSON file feeding the data to this chart, my question is how could I get this file automatically with R. When I try to open the JSON in a new tab outside the inspector "Response" tab, I get an "Unauthorized" message. There is any way of doing this or every time I would have to manually copy the JSON from the inspector and update my R script?

[image]

In my case, I am interested in the "PortalDias" response. Thank you.

[URL PORTAL DIAS](https://xx9p7hp1p7.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/prod/PortalDias)

Comment: Can you put the url for PortalDias? Right click on it and you should see options to copy.

Comment: I edit the question with the URL!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set some headers to prevent this "Unauthorized" message. I copied them from the 'Headers' section in the browser 'Network' window.

```
library(curl)
library(jsonlite)

url <- "https://xx9p7hp1p7.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/prod/PortalDias"

h <- new_handle()
handle_setheaders(h, Host = "xx9p7hp1p7.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com",
                  `Accept-Encoding` = "gzip, deflate, br",
                  `X-Parse-Application-Id` = "unAFkcaNDeXajurGB7LChj8SgQYS2ptm")
fromJSON(rawToChar(curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = h)$content))

# $results
#      objectId label                createdAt                updatedAt  qtd_confirmado qtd_obito
# 1  6vr9rUPbd4 26/02 2020-03-25T16:25:53.970Z 2020-03-25T22:25:42.967Z               1       123
# 2  FUNHS00sng 27/02 2020-03-25T16:27:34.040Z 2020-03-25T22:25:55.169Z               0        34
# 3  t4qW51clpj 28/02 2020-03-25T19:08:36.689Z 2020-03-25T22:26:02.427Z               0        35
# ...
```

Comment: Wow. I was looping through the JSON to populate a df, this already does it, amazing. Thank you.